# ios: uitableview - how to remove first section

Tags: ios, uitableview, header

I have several sections in a `uitableview` as shown here:

[image]

How do I hide the first section header e.g. `Men`.

Comment: Link to screen is dead

Comment: @SergePashkevich added picture for you.

Comment: @Ketan what do you want exactly ? Don't want section header title ?

Comment: @Bhargavi Yes, I don't want the first section header title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding GetHeightForHeader in UITableViewSource, and returning 0 it's the first section

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
if (section == 0) return 0; 
    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight; 
}
```

In Xamarin, it would look like:

```
public override float GetHeightForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
{
  if (section == 0)
    return 0;
  return tableView.SectionHeaderHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The obj-c equivalent is
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return 0;
    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight;

}`